# Low B keeps going out of tune

Tags: electric-guitar, strings, repair, intonation, guitar-neck

My seven string guitar has a problem. The low B constantly goes out of tune. Whenever I bend it, I immediately have to re tune it. The place I bought it said it was probably the nut but I am not understanding how that could be. Is there a quick fix without having to take it to a shop? I live a long way from one. Thank you guys

Comment: Does this happen every time you pluck the string and retune - and does pitch go down or up?

Comment: Yes, it always goes down I believe. It isn't after I pluck it- it is directly after I bend it or play for a minute or less. Thanks

Comment: This is a pretty specific problem, not sure if it's good for the exchange. At any rate, some things to think about: is the string new? New strings stretch. Is it well tied to the machine tuner? If not, it will not stay. Is your tuner loose? Is your guitar warped? Get yourself a Floyd Rose and you'll have sunshine.

Comment: a few questions: What string gauge are you using on the low B? Are you using a fixed bridge or a floating bridge, and what model of guitar is it?

Comment: How long have you been trying with this string? Did you pre-stretch it at all - some strings are a nightmare when new so it might just be that.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like there are too few details about what the problem is for us to give meaningful answers.

Comment: I am sorry guys, this is a PRS 7 string with plate style bridge. I use D'Addario XL110's and I do stretch my strings out several times before I start playing. It is definitely not due to lack of stretching and it is only the low B that stays out of tune. I am going to trick this guitar out a bit later on: new pickups, hardware, etc. just for fun and preference. Did this give enough detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you stretch your strings and would prefer not to have your guitar worked on at a shop, a quick fix would be a **lubricant**.

Before the Floyd Rose tremolo system existed, lots of players would apply lubricants to the nuts of their guitars as needed. This allows the strings to slide through the nut when bent or when used heavily by a whammy bar. Van Halen has mentioned in numerous interviews his hassle to keep his guitar in tune pre-Floyd. Even players without locking string systems, like Guthrie Govan, have mentioned the necessity to using string lubricants to allow them to play "irresponsibly."

You can either make your own or order a notable brand (Big Bends Nut Sauce is very popular). If you want to experiment and make your own there are many different "recipes" out on the web, but the majority of them consist of the lead from a pencil mixed with vaseline to make a paste. Some people even use Teflon Oil.

**A warning:** *when you apply anything to your guitar, do it sparingly.*